# How to evaluate the complexity of a code

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Here is my code for computing the product of sequences of matrices

```
def product(A,B):
    """
    Computing the product of two given matrices
    
    Args:
    - A (tuple): a matrix of size 2 x 2
    - B (tuple): a matrix of size 2 x 2
    
    Return:
    - product (tuple): a product of two matrices A and B
    """
    
    product = []
    
    for i in range(2):
        row = []
        for k in range(2):
            row.append(A[i][0]*B[0][k] + A[i][1]*B[1][k])
        product.append(tuple(row))
        # print(row)
    return tuple(product)
```

```
def random_word(n):
    """
    Generate random words of length n from two letters A and B.
    Args:
    - n (integer): the length of the string
    Return: A random string of size n including A and B
    """
    return "".join(random.choice(['A', 'B']) for _ in range(n))

def naive(u, A, B):
    """
    Generating naive multiplication for matrix sequences.
    
    Args:
    - u (string): the given random word generated by random_word() function.
    - A (tuple): the given matrix A.
    - B (tuple): the given matrix B.
    
    Return: product of sequence of matrices including A and B.
    """
    matrix_dict = {
    "A": A,
    "B": B
    }
    converted_u = [matrix_dict[element] for element in u]
    sequence_product = identity() # assign intial value for the product of sequential multiplication
    for i in range(len(u)):
        sequence_product = product(sequence_product,converted_u[i])
    return sequence_product
```

Now, I evaluate the complexity of my code as follows:

- The matrices A and B are assumed to take $\mathcal{O}(1)$ bits in memory. These are fixed-size matrices and do not depend on the size of $u$.
- The list $converted\_u$ stores intermediate matrices and its size is directly proportional to the size of $u$. In the worst case, $u$ can contain $n$ elements, resulting in $converted\_u$ requiring $\Theta(n)$ bits to store the intermediate matrices.
- The $sequence\_product$ variable stores the cumulative product of matrices in the 'naive' approach. In the worst case, $sequence\_product$ can also store up to n matrices. Since each matrix has a constant size, the memory usage of $sequence\_product$ is $\Theta(n)$.

When we add up the memory usage of these data structures, we have:
$$\mathcal{O}(1) + \Theta(n) + \Theta(n) = \Theta(n).$$
Therefore, in the worst case, the coefficients of the result of the sequence of products problem indeed use $\Theta(n)$ bits.

I wonder if there is anything I have made incorrectly.

Comment: We're not a coding site, and questions asking us to analyze a chunk of code are typically considered off-topic here.  If in the process of doing the analysis, you discover a conceptual confusion about some step, then you can ask about how to handle that particular aspect.   Also, we discourage 'here are my calculations, are they correct?' questions as they can only be answered with a yes or no, which is unlikely to be correct.